# Angular2 Template parse error after error code removed

Tags: angular, debugging, kendo-grid

I'm working with ng2 and kendo-ui grid component. I've had no issues until I went to add another property to kendo grid component, and now I seem to be stuck in some strange compiler fugue state.

**Error in Chrome Dev console:**

```debug
Unexpected character "a" ("
    </kendo-grid-column>
  </kendo-grid
    [ERROR ->]appRowClick
    [ngStyle]="{
      'height': showAdditionalFilters ? 'calc(100vh - 280px)' : 'calc("): ng:///FooBarModule/FooBarComponent.html@214:4
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
      'width': 'calc(100vw - 130px)'}">

</div>
[ERROR ->]"): ng:///FooBarModule/FooBarComponent.html@220:0
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("
      'width': 'calc(100vw - 130px)'}">

</div>
[ERROR ->]"): ng:///FooBarModule/FooBarComponent.html@220:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1690)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate (compiler.es5.js:14132)
    at compiler.es5.js:14118
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1679)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateOnly (compiler.es5.js:14118)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (compiler.es5.js:14100)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15129)
    at compiler.es5.js:26806
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.es5.js:26805
```

**foo.bar.html (with ngStyle):**

```angular
  <kendo-grid
    appRowClick
    [ngStyle]="{
       'height': showAdditionalFilters ? 'calc(100vh - 280px)' : 'calc(100vh - 180px)',
       'width': 'calc(100vw - 130px)'}"
    [data]="gridData"
    [selectable]="true"
    [sortable]="true"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
    (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)">...</kendo-grid>
```

So I remove the entire [ngStyle] input expect that would resolve the issue, however I'm still receiving the error. The code doesn't exist anywhere else in the app.

Does anybody know what could be the issue? I've tried restarting `ng serve` and refreshing browser, but neither seem to work.

**foo.bar.html (without ngStyle)**:

```angular
  <kendo-grid
    appRowClick
    [data]="gridData"
    [selectable]="true"
    [sortable]="true"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
    (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)">...</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: Besides the line breaks, your ngStyle directive looks fine. What is the `appRowClick` attribute?

Comment: does it compile if you remove "appRowClick"?

Comment: I've removed `appRowClick` directive and moved the ngStyle binding expression to the same line and I'm still seeing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have newlines inside binding expressions

```
[ngStyle]="{
   'height': showAdditionalFilters ? 'calc(100vh - 280px)' : 'calc(100vh - 180px)',
   'width': 'calc(100vw - 130px)'}"
```

should be

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'height': showAdditionalFilters ? 'calc(100vh - 280px)' : 'calc(100vh - 180px)', 'width': 'calc(100vw - 130px)'}"
```

Comment: I've removed the entire [ngStyle] input and I'm still seeing error. Thoughts?

Comment: I guess it's not from the code you posted then. Can you please add the new error message to your question?

Comment: And you're correct, and I'm a clown. I somehow pasted the same code at the bottom of the html so it was all jacked-up. Thanks for you help.